# What happens when you call IPython with the `--matplotlib` command-line argument?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I could only find this from their help section.

> Configure matplotlib for interactive use with the default matplotlib

I have been having performance issues plotting using matplotlib.pyplot with the IPython command-line until I tried the `--matplotlib` option.

**Example**

Without `--matplotlib`

```
 $ ipython
 In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl

 In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 In [3]: mpl.get_backend()
 Out[3]: u'Qt4Agg'

 In [4]: plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
 Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb473198>]
 # IPython command-line becomes entirely unresponsive, must restart IPython to become usable again
```

With `--matplotlib`

```
 $ ipython --matplotlib
 In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl

 In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 In [3]: mpl.get_backend()
 Out[3]: u'Qt4Agg'

 In [4]: plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
 Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe1d68>]
 # IPython command-line remains responsive
```

I suspect a side-effect of using the `--matplotlib` argument is boosting my performance, but I'd like to know how.

**Setup**

- IPython: 3.0.0
- matplotlib: 1.4.3
- Python: 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)
- Windows 7 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the equivalent of setting `plt.interactive(True)` (i.e. turning interactive mode on, or equivalently running `plt.ion()`), so that when a figure instance is created, you still have control of the terminal. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#controlling-interactive-updating) for more information.

For example:

```
$ ipython --matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.isinteractive() 
# True
```

As opposed to:

```
$ ipython

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.isinteractive() 
# False
```

As a side note, in your first example, the command line will remain unresponsive until you close the figure that is created by your `plt.plot` command. Once you close that window, you should regain control of the command line.

Comment: Thanks Tom, although I think something additional is happening as I still see the performance issues after using `plt.ion()`. In my first example, the figure is never displayed as I don't call `plt.show()`. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough originally, but by 'unresponsive' I meant each keystroke takes about 1/4 second to appear, rather than simply blocking input.